# Is "Universityhood" a valid English word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, neologisms, morphology, derivational-morphology

This is a theme during the foundation day of a college, "Nurturing Elders' Legacy and Aspiring for Excellent Quest as a Keystone into University". Isn't it universityhood instead of just university?
Which is a better theme, "Nurturing Elders' Legacy and Aspiring for Excellent Quest as a Keystone into University(hood)" or "Nurturing Legacy, Aspiring Excellence into Universityhood"?

Comment: No, it's not an English word.  _`X` College has achieved Universityhood_ might mean that it has been renamed as _`X` University_, but it would be a bizarre way to say that. Furthermore, the title isn't grammatical English, and doesn't mean anything I can understand. Who's nurturing whom? Which elders? What legacies? Who's aspiring? What does "Excellent Quest" mean? What needs a keystone? And who's going to University -- elders, nurturers, the author?

Comment: I suppose it meant something in the original language it's been translated from, but your entire "theme name" is really just a meaningless string of words in English. That's not going to change, whether you use ***university*** or the non-existent term ***universityhood***

Comment: What I meant to ask was whether it is okay to change the original theme ("Nurturing Elders' Legacy and Aspiring for Excellent Quest as a Keystone into University") into this: "Nurturing Legacy, Aspiring Excellence into Universityhood"? The college is going to be converted into a university after compliance of requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have placed two questions for the price of one. I'm answering your question title: *Is "Universityhood" a valid English word?*

Well, it depends on what you mean with a *valid word*.
Is it in any major, authoritative dictionary? No.
 Will a pedant or prescriptive linguist yell at you for using it? Yes, probably.
Is it a valid [neologism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism)? Yes.

So the answer to whether it is a "valid word" or not depends on the personal, subjective stance on neologisms of whomever you ask. You are coining a word to describe a particular thing that isn't very well-described by other, existing words. Some people will consider that to be fair game. Others will insist that you should only use totally correct, authoritatively prescribed English. This becomes a difference of opinion.

So there's no definitive answer. One thing to consider is that *Universityhood* sounds really *ugly*. It's not very pleasant to say, and it handles somewhat awkwardly. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I'm noting that someone downvoted both the question and this answer within a space of a few seconds. May I ask why?

Comment: Probably envious trolls, who do not know how to answer.

Comment: @Newb I didn’t downvote your answer (which answers the title question eminently), but the question body itself (or at least the context in which the word asked about is to be used) is an incomprehensible mess that makes no sense—so I did downvote that.